# Transaction values exchanged even if transaction rejected, and double values exchanged if transaction confirmed

Tags: solidity, web3js, metamask

I'm trying to perform a function that exchanges one token for another, but I'm getting a very strange bug. If I call the function in web3, I get the standard metamask popup asking whether to confirm or reject the transaction. Now what's happening is if I hit reject, the value exchange still happens, even though there is no transaction on metamask nor on my ganache cli, just the values are updated on metamask. Then if I confirm the transaction, the transaction goes through as normal, except that double the expected value is exchanged.

Occasionally I get `RPC Error: MetaMask Tx Signature: User denied transaction signature.` as expected, yet the value is still exchanged. I've tried restarting my ganache cli, resetting my accounts on metamask, and even reinstalling metamask, but still the same.

**Solidity**

```
function deposit(uint amount) public {
    require(daitoken.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amount), 'transferFrom failed');
    emit Transfer(msg.sender, address(this), amount);
    require(ldai.mint(msg.sender, amount), 'mint failed');
    emit Mint(msg.sender, amount);
    emit Deposit(msg.sender, amount);
  }
```

**Web3**

```
const num = this.state.amount * (10**18);
    this.props.contract.methods.deposit(num.toString()).send({from: this.props.account});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your code looks fine, and there are no bug reports anywhere matching the issue you are describing, I suggest diagnosing if the bug comes from MetaMask by trying another wallet. Also, try another version of web3.js.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but no luck yet...